# How to access the file system from Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

In express.js I can write a controller that:

1. accesses the file system
2. reads the contents of a directory, and
3. sends that information as a local variable to the view.

I'm not sure how to go about this in Nuxt.js because I can't require the `fs` module from the component. Is there anywhere where I can populate a variable with a list of files in the server (for example, in the `static` folder) so that the component has access to it?

Answer (score 8):

To require modules on the serverside, use [serverMiddleware](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/)

```
# nuxt.config.js
module.exports = {
  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api', handler: '~/api/index.js' }
  ]
}
```

Now you can `require('fs')` in `api/index.js`